# How is MarshalByRefObject implemented?

Tags: .net, remoting, marshalbyrefobject

I would like to know how the `MarshalByRefObject` is implimented and why does it make it possible to pass objects by reference in remoting.

Is it possible because of the implementation of the `MarshalByRefObject` class, or does the remoting libraries just check whether the class derived from `MarshalByRefObject`?

Comment: It has been answered before here

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720703/is-marshalbyrefobject-special

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of the MarshalByRefObject class itself is not that special; the important magic is implemented by the CLR (especially the JIT) at a low level. This has been [discussed already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720703/is-marshalbyrefobject-special) as Jacob mentioned; some of the most useful information is in [an article by 'cbrumme'](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/07/14/51495.aspx).