# How to define enums in a class abiding by an interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, derived-class

The interface is:

```
public interface CommonPluginInterface
{
    string GetPluginName();
    string GetPluginType();
    bool ElaborateReport();
}
```

now I want all derived classes to identify themselves through a string and an enum. For the string it's easy for it's hard coded:

```
public class PluginReport_Excel : MarshalByRefObject, CommonPluginInterface
{
    public string GetPluginName()
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
}
```

but additionally I want it to identify through an enum also. So I thought about putting in the interface but interface can't contain members.

So I thought about making

```
public class CommonPluginClass
{
    private enum ePluginType { UNKNOWN, EXCEL, EXCEL_SM, RTF}
    private ePluginType pluginType;
}
```

and making the derived class derive ALSO from that but this is not possible for it says:

> Class 'PluginReport_Excel' cannot have multiple base classes: 'MarshalByRefObject' and 'CommonPluginClass'

and I need MarshalByRefObject.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313243/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an enum separately and define it as a return type for the GetPluginType method.

```
public enum ePluginType 
{ 
    UNKNOWN, 
    EXCEL, 
    EXCEL_SM, 
    RTF
} 

public interface CommonPluginInterface
{
    string GetPluginName();
    ePluginType GetPluginType();
    bool ElaborateReport();
}

public class PluginReport_Excel : MarshalByRefObject, CommonPluginInterface
{
    public ePluginType GetPluginType()
    {
        return ePluginType.EXCEL;
    }

    //implement other interface members
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a property on the interface with the enum´s type:

```
public interface CommonPluginInterface
{
    string GetPluginName();
    bool ElaborateReport();
    ePluginType PluginType { get; }
}
```

Now all implementing classes also have to set the property accordingly. However you´ll ned the enumeration to be public.

```
public class PluginReport_Excel : MarshalByRefObject, CommonPluginInterface
{
    public string GetPluginName()
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
    public PluginType { get { return ePluginType.Excel; } }
}
```

Alternativly when you want to use the `GetPluginType`-method you may simply convert the enums value to string:

```
public class PluginReport_Excel : MarshalByRefObject, CommonPluginInterface
{
    public string GetPluginName()
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
    public string GetPluginType()
    {
        return this.PluginType.ToString();
    }
    public PluginType { get { return ePluginType.Excel; } }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a `MarshalByRefCommonPluginClass`?

```
public class MarshalByRefCommonPluginClass : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private enum ePluginType { UNKNOWN, EXCEL, EXCEL_SM, RTF}
    private ePluginType pluginType;
}
```

As an aside, [naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx) would normally mean interfaces have an 'I' prefix (`ICommonPlugin`) and types would use capital letters (`EPluginType`).